# How to find Azure Storage Blob by name suffix without enumerating whole container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Having big amount of blobs inside Azure virtual directories:

```
VirtualDirectory1/file1
VirtualDirectory1/file2
...
VirtualDirectory1/fileN
...
VirtualDirectoryK/file1
VirtualDirectoryK/file2
...
VirtualDirectoryK/fileM
```

I need a fast way to find all blobs that ends with the certain **suffix** (for instance "file1").
As to prefixes there is a way to fetch only blobs that starts with some name:

```
blobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix: "prefixHere")
```

The following approach to fetch blobs with certain **suffix** results in **fetching the full container** and its filtering on the client.

```
var blobsFound =
    blobContainer
    .ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true)
    .OfType<ICloudBlob>()
    .Where(b => b.Name.EndsWith("file1"))
    .ToList();
```

It could be clearly seen using Fiddler to capture traffic:

[image: fiddler output]

Is there a way to find all blobs by the suffix on the Azure side, without fetching full list of blobs to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to find all blobs by the suffix on the Azure side,
>   without fetching full list of blobs to the client?

Unfortunately no. Blob service only supports filtering by blob prefix and not by suffix. Your only option would be to list blobs and then do client side filtering.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see any workarounds to quickly find blobs? I see the only way - flatten container and get rid of virtual directories at all, then use search by prefix...

Comment: You could store them in a way that retrieval by prefix becomes easier. Other convoluted approach would be to make use of table storage to store blob URLs and other relevant information and then doing searches in the table to get blob URL.